# Question about WPF FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) method

Tags: wpf, panel

When creating a custom `Panel`, we need to override `FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)` and `FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)` to organise our custom layout of items. The MSDN [FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) page states that the return value of type `System.Windows.Size`
 should be "The actual size used".

However, if the actual size used by the items is smaller than the size of the container, then the item content is centred in the container. By this I mean that a bounds rectangle of the size returned contains all the items and is centred in the container.

I tried setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties on the `ListBox` that uses my custom `Panel`, but it made no difference. Strangely though, if I return the unadjusted `finalSize` input variable instead of the actual size used, then my items appear just as expected and the custom `Panel` works fine. Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is? Also, is it possible to position the bounds rectangle containing the items when returning the actual size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size returned by `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` is the size of the element doing the returning, not the size of its content.  Just give your panel a background and that's the size we're talking about.

You can only position the top-left of a panel (or any other element) with the cooperation its parent container.  In general your only two choices are `Margin="x,y,0,0"` to provide positive or negative offsets relative to the top-left the container gives you, or to use a `Canvas` as a parent container and use `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.

Comment: Ah, now that makes more sense, thanks. Rick 'Got the Answer' Sladkey does it again! :)